# Add another dimension into array cart

Tags: php

I have a shopping cart, which works just fine, but I would like to store type of goods (for example color, size, etc.).

**Here is a function that gets items from shopping cart**

```
public static function getCart() {
        if((isset($_SESSION['cart'])) && count($_SESSION['cart'])>0) {
            $ids = "";
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {
                $ids = $ids . $id . ",";
            } 
            $ids = rtrim($ids, ',');

            $dotaz = dibi::fetchAll("SELECT * FROM eshop_products WHERE idProduct IN ({$ids})");
            return $dotaz;
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

**And function that adds items to shopping cart**

```
public static function addToCart($data) {

        $id = $data['id']; 
        $quantity = $data['qty']; 
        $varianta = $data['varianty']; //THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO ADD TO SESSION ARRAY


        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        }


        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$id] += $quantity;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $quantity;
        }   
    }
```

Is there some easy way to do that? I googled some tutorials, but still no success.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. What are you having an problem with? Just save the `varianty` value the same way you did for `cart`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a hint for you:

```
$id = $data['id']; 
$quantity = $data['qty']; 
$varianta = $data['varianty']; //THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO ADD TO SESSION ARRAY

$cart = array();

array_push($cart, array(
  'id' => $id,
  'quantity' => $quantity,
  'varianta' => $varianta
));
```